# homebrew password after removal of mac users password

Tags: mac, passwords, homebrew

I installed homebrew while I had a password assigned to my mac user. Everytime I installed a cask which needed password I was able to use my mac users password. So far so good.

Problem: I recently removed the password of my mac user. But brew keeps asking for password during installation of some casks.

Question: Why does brew still need a password? Which password am I supposed to type in? My old password which was assigned to my mac user?

Answer (score 0):

Installs need admin permission.
Admin permission needs a password.
An account with no password cannot give permission.

Add an admin password.

<sup>tbh, I'm surprised it let you remove it completely. It should have prevented you doing that.</sup>